# CsvDataException : Number of fields invalid

Tags: django, csv

I work on a Django projet where I have to create an application to import a Csv into a model that already exists (I cannot modifie this model).

For exemple, I have a Sates ("Pays") model that contains 3 fields : name, code, and nationality :

```
class Pays(models.Model):
pays = models.CharField(max_length=150)
codeiso3166alpha2 = models.CharField(max_length=2)
nationalite = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
maj = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
class Meta:
    db_table = u'Pays'
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.pays
```

Here is a piss of my csv :

```
AFGHANISTAN;AF;Afgane
AFRIQUE DU SUD;ZA;Sud-africaine
ALBANIE;AL;Albanaise
```

For that, I used the module "django-adaptator". Here is my first code that works, the data have been imported aswell :

The models.py of my application named "remplirPays":

```
# coding: utf-8

from django.db import models
from adaptor.model import CsvModel
from adaptor.fields import CharField, IntegerField, FloatField

from polyc2n.models import Pays  #that is the model that already exists


class MyCSVModel(CsvModel):

    name = CharField  (match = "pays")
    abrev = CharField (match ="codeiso3166alpha2")
    nationalite = CharField (match ="nationalite")

    class Meta:
        delimiter = ";"
        has_header = True
        dbModel = Pays
```

Here is my views.py:

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from adaptor.model import CsvModel
from remplirPays.models import MyCSVModel


path = "pays.csv"

def DataPays(request):
    MyCSVModel.import_data(data = open(path))
    return HttpResponse("Import is ok")
```

However, to optimise my code and for the purpose that somone can easyly use it, I wanted to use a "CsvDbModel" and not a CsvModel beacause  I don’t want to re-declare a CSV model whereas the Django model already exists.

Here is the problem, my code is the following one :

models.py :

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.db import models
from polyc2n.models import Pays
from adaptor.model import CsvDbModel

class MyCSVDbModel(CsvDbModel):
    class Meta:
        dbModel = Pays
        delimiter = ";"
        has_header = True
```

My views.py:

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import models
from polyc2n.models import Pays
from adaptor.model import CsvDbModel
from remplirPays.models import MyCSVDbModel
from django.http import HttpResponse

path = "pays.csv"

def DataPays(request):
    MyCSVDbModel.import_data(data = open(path))
    return HttpResponse("import is ok")
```

And when i run, i got an error :

```
Exception Type: CsvDataException
Exception Value: Line 1: Number of fields invalid
```

I don't understand why i get this when my first code worked aswell....

I hope you can help me, thx for reading.

Ps: I apologize for my english, I am not a native speaker and I tryed to do my best

Answer (score 0):

May be before you had use customize model, where you have provided fields you required , second time you have used default(CsvDbModel) you haven't add your fileds in it, model what django has provided which may not contain the field whatever you required or trying to import into database, so showing this exception

you can change your second models.py as

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.db import models
from polyc2n.models import Pays
from adaptor.model import CsvDbModel
class MyCSVDbModel(CsvDbModel):
    name = CharField  (match = "pays")
    abrev = CharField (match ="codeiso3166alpha2")
    nationalite = CharField (match ="nationalite")
    class Meta:
        dbModel = Pays
        delimiter = ";"
        has_header = True
```

Comment: The puropose of using CvsDbModel is that you don't need to re-declare a CSV model, if you re-declare one so you have to use CsvModel and not CsvDbModel

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION :  Even if it is not shown in django admin, the "maj" attribut from the Pays table :

```
maj = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

is considered. So i had to exclude him :

```
class Meta:
    exclude = ['maj']
```